# loop in net core main, or listening method

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

Im blocked with the follow,

What is the best way to create a listening process with netcore/c#, I'm looking for something like 
the method listening on nodejs with 
http.createServer().listening(),//this is a loop, that waiting for a request, I need something similar but in netcore console.

I tried this:
infinite loop with a "while", but this way consume the processor, 
the other way is with Console.ReadLine() like this:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
while (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Could you please explain what are you trying to achieve. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: I added an example here

Answer (score 0):

we suppose that I have a Main.cs file with the Main method, then I wrote one function asynchronous like that:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Task.Run(async () => {
                await AsyncMain();
            } );

            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
            while (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static async Task<int> AsyncMain()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

for example into method AsyncMain (thats example is no real code), maybe I can execute a proccess that will be react with other thing, but if I dont wrote the "while" the program does not wait, run and finished